# Prolog: sister/brother relationship

Tags: prolog, relationship

I am trying to establish a relationship model in Prolog but the sister relationship turns out to be a fail. I am wondering what a good solution would be to this. I am a beginner and this is my first programme, any help is welcome.

```
man(adam).
man(peter).
man(paul).
man(carlos).
man(willem).

woman(marry).
woman(eve).
woman(greta).
woman(lisa).

parent(adam, peter). 
parent(eve, peter).
parent(adam, paul).
parent(marry, paul).
parent(adam, willem).
parent(adam, lisa).
parent(eve, willem).
parent(eve, lisa).
parent(greta, adam).
parent(carlos, adam).

father(F, C) :-
   man(F),
   parent(F, C).

mother(M,C) :-
   woman(M),
   parent(M, C).

grandparent(P, C):-
   parent(P, K),
   parent(K, C).

sister(x,y) :-
   woman(x),
   mother(m, x),
   father(f, x),
   mother(m, y),
   father(f, y).
```

Comment: yes, it was. quite a cool language!

Comment: Yes it is :p pattern-matching is the coolest assignment I've had in prolog (for example: solve sudokus). Also, add the "homework" tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use upper case letters for the variables in your `sister\2` predicate. In your code you have lower case letters, which are atoms, so this will always fail unless you have people called `x`,`y`,`f` and `m`.

Also, add `X \= Y` to prevent X being her own sister.